# PC 1 Long 2 Short Beeps, No BIOS

Tags: memory, graphics-card, bios

I just built a PC and it just makes 1 long and 2 short beeps. I'm pretty sure it's not the graphics card because it is working fine with all fans on and pcie ports work. I tried both ports for graphics card and they work the same. I think it's the RAM.

My specs:

- Motherboard-Asus M5A97 LE R2.0
- Graphics Card-Asus Radeon HD 7870 Direct CU II
- RAM-Corsair Vengeance LP 8 GB 1 Stick Black Version
- Processor- AMD FX Black Version
- Power Supply- EVGA 500B 500W Bronze
- And a SATA Hard Drive

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that [asus's website](http://support.asus.com/Troubleshooting/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=M5A97%20PRO&os=&no=978) says 1 long beep, 2 short beeps is a memory issue, I'd say you're right.

Go [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M5A97_R20/#support_QVL) to see compatible RAM for that board.